# how can I display html with variable from database in blade

Tags: html, database, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

I have HTML code with variable in database I want to display the code with html design and variable data in blade

Database Code

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
<li>
@foreach ($block->options as $option)
<a>{{$option->name}}</a>
@endforeach
</li>
</ul>
```

Blade View

```
@foreach ($blocks as $block)
{!! $block !!}
@endforeach
```

I have already display the html code but the variable still as strings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geazv.png)

Comment: Please explain your question, it's kinda hard to understand!!!

Comment: I need to display in blade rows contain html code with variables when I use {!! !!} the html code works fine but the variable not

Comment: I tried use eval() function the variable works fine but the html design has a lot of below code sample
\r\n      
\r\n      
\r\n  \r\n      \r\n          
\r\n\r\n      \r\n      \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Before saving your data in database, use the php built-in function `htmlentities()` on the html code string like this:

```
$html_code = '<p class="any-class">Lorem Ipsum / Random Text</p>';
$encode = htmlentities($html_code);
/* Insert the $encode in the database cell where you want to store html */
```

And then when displaying the cell data with html tags using blade, you do this `{{!! html_entity_decode($block) !!}}`

This will work fine!!! Cheers!!